# Find all <a>, children of a certain <div>

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to loop with BeautifulSoup over all `<a href=...>` that are included in a `<h2>`, themselves in a `<div class="myclass">` :

```
<a href="www.example.com">Not selected</a> 
<div class="myclass">
  <a href="www.example.com">Not selected</a> 
  <h2>
    <a href="www.example.com">SELECTED!</a> 
  </h2>
</div>
```

I was thinking about something like this, but I can imagine that BeautifulSoup can do such filtering without any `if link.parent == ...` tests:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(req), "lxml")

for link in soup.select('a[href]'):
    if link.parent == ...   # tests
       print link
```

**How to do this with BeautifulSoup?**

Answer (score 3):

You can just `findAll` step by step and advance your way to the `a`s you want:

```
for div in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "myclass"}):
    for h2 in div.findAll("h2"):
        for a in h2.findAll("a"):
            print a
```

Or you can just use a css selector in `select`:

```
soup.select('.myclass h2 a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful soup supports CSS class selectors, [relevant documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

So you could make a query along the lines of:

```
soup.find_all('.myclass > h2 > a')
```

So that's all anchor tags who are a child of the heading which are the child of the div.

Answer (score 1):

use using css selector:

```
soup.select('div h2 a')
```

Comment: This works. What's the difference between this and `soup.find_all('.myclass > h2 > a')` (doesn't work in my case) ?

Comment: If you have multiple class of same name inside the single <div> like:

    <div class='class-1'>  
        <div class='class-demo'></div>
        <div class='class-demo'></div>
        <div class='class-demo'></div>
    </div>
Then you will use find_all() to search every class-demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
divs = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'myclass'})
for div in divs:
    links = div.findAll('h2 > a')
    for link in links:
        print link
```